# How does twitter use UITableView to make this page?

Tags: ios, uitableview, twitter

I would like to create a page in my App and it should look like `Twitter`'s `Me page`. However, I really don't know how they make it. [image]

I suppose there is a main `UITableView` and three sub-`UITableViews`. But how do they combine together?

Currently I create one main `ViewController` and three sub `ViewController`. in the main `ViewController` I put one `UITableView` and one UISegmentedControl in the table header. This table has only one cell and put three sub `ViewController` in that cell. I can use segmentedcontrol to change sub viewcontroller's hidden value. It looks like `twitter` but the table doesn't work smoothly like `twitter` at all...  `Twitter`'s table works so smoothly among three tables and I really don't know how `Twitter` make it...

Anyone has idea??

Comment: I think that in all possibility that they use UICollection views more than table views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done using `UISegmentControl` take a look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol. There are 2 approaches one is to use same UITableView and based on segment change the data source. This induces reload on every segment change. If you want to use Single Responsibility Principle, it is better to use 3 view controllers along with `UISegmentControl`

Comment: Hi @New16, I did add UISegmentedControl. Just update my question and add this part. For the 2 approaches, the first one, the table can scroll smoothly but each time you reload the data source, the table will scroll back to the top. (Tweeter won't). The second one is what i did currently, but the problem is when scroll the table, it doesn't scroll smoothly like Tweeter. Personally I believe Tweeter use the second approach. just i don't know how they make table scroll smoothly...

Comment: @Alexander Huang I am imagining that you are using the `NSFetchedResultsController`, in this case you need to handle the setting the delegate and `performFetch()` in `viewWillAppear` and set the delegate to nil in `viewWillDisappear`. Check how you are loading the image. Scrolling will improve if you load the cell information in `willDisplayCell` rather than `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Yes, I use NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve data. The delegate you talked about is the one of NSFetchedResultsController, right? And you think I choose the second approach you mention is correct ?

Comment: Yeah, the second approach is correct. The delegate is of `NSFetchedResultsController`'s.

Comment: @AlexanderHuang did you get the solution yet. If your scrolling is not smooth you need to debug the UI of `UITableViewCell`. There are so many blogs for example https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.iszg9bf4r. You can check what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try **UISegmentedControl** to combine these three viewcontroller instead of separated ones :D

Comment: Hi, @Rango, I did use UISegmentedControl to switch among 3 sub viewcontroller. I didn't mention it in the original question and now I update my question and add this part. But still, the issue is, it doesn't scroll smoothly like tweeter. That is what i want to know how Tweeter did that.